# Confusion over Lambda functions in this code

Tags: python, function, lambda

This is a piece of open source code I found online. I am trying to figure it out but having some functions, I am having particular trouble with the Lambda functions in it, and why I am not able to print values from it.

Below is the code, and commented out all the lines of code that I have tried, but ended u[ crashing the code. I am wondering why they crash the code.

There is one print statement that works, but only in the for loop. Outside of the for loop it crashes.

```
fo = open('outp3.txt','w')
with open('C-small-practice.in','r') as fi:
    rr = lambda: fi.readline().strip()
    rrI = lambda: int(rr())
    rrM = lambda: map(int,rr().split())
    #print rr() ## This print statement doesn't work
    #print rrI() ## This print statement doesn't work
    #print rrM() ## This print statement doesn't work
    #T1= rr() ## this doesn't work/crashes the program
    #T2= rrI() ## this doesn't work/crashes the program
    #T3= rrM() ## this doesn't work/crashes the program
    #print T1 ## This print statement doesn't work
    #print T2 ## This print statement doesn't work
    #print T3 ## This print statement doesn't work
    for tc in xrange(rrI()):
        N = rrI()
        #M = rr() ## this doesn't work/crashes the program
        #O = rrM() ## this doesn't work/crashes the program
        print N #this works!
        #print M
        #print O
        A = [rr().split() for _ in xrange(N)]
        zetaans = solve(N,A)
        zeta = "Case #%i: "%(tc+1) + str(zetaans)
        fo.write(zeta+'\n')
fo.close()
```

Here is the input that it uses

```
3
3
HYDROCARBON COMBUSTION
QUAIL COMBUSTION
QUAIL BEHAVIOR
3
CODE JAM
SPACE JAM
PEARL JAM
2
INTERGALACTIC PLANETARY
PLANETARY INTERGALACTIC
```

Comment: This code is painful to look at but seems valid,  and "it doesn't work" or "it crashes the program" don't really help to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more info. dejvuth found what was going on and give me the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rr()` reads a line.

`rrI()` reads a line and converts it into `int`. So, the `for` loop will run `3` times, following your input.

For each time `N = rrI()` is called, so the next number is read. Then, `rr().split()` is called `N` times. So, `A` is a list of length `N`, where each element itself is a list, corresponding to a line in the input and splitting by space into words.

You can notice that the input file format must match perfectly with the code, i.e. when calling `rrI()` you expect to see an `int`, not a string.

Adding addition `print rr()` or `print rrI()` crashes the code, because you also read addition lines, and therefore no longer follow the input format.

Comment: I get it now! I was used to using 'readlines'. which reads all the lines. I didn't realize 'readline' reads only one line then moves on to the next, so it gives a difference answer each time its called.